# Cakephp How to validate my D.O.B field so that the age will not be greater than the period of residence entered

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have two fields in my form that should correspond to each other.If a users enters the date of birth,in the D.O.B field,he/she must not be allowed to enter a period of residence greater than the D.O.B

my two fields in the add.ctp are as follows

```
echo $this->Form->input('DOB',array('label' => 'Date of birth*', 'minYear' => 1900,    'maxYear' => 2000));


echo $this->Form->input('period_of_residence', array('label' =>'Period of residence in   Zimbabwe'));
```

So now i don't know how i validate the two so that the user cannot enter a period of residence greater than the age.Even if it validates on submission i like it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own custom validation function in your model like so:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'DOB' => array(
            'rule' => 'checkDOB',
            'message' => 'DOB cannot be greater than period of residence.'
        )
    );

    public function checkDOB($check) {
        return strtotime($check['DOB']) < strtotime($this->data['MyModel']['period_of_residence']);
    }
}
```