# CakePHP: Validate a user is over 13 year

Tags: cakephp

I have the following validation rule in my model:

```
'dob' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Date of Birth is required'
            ),
            'age' => array(
                'rule' => array('comparison', '>=', 13),
                'message' => 'You must be over 13 years old'
            )
        )
```

What I'm trying to achieve is validate that the user is over 13 years old...

The date is created like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Profile.dob', array('label' => 'Date of Birth'
                                        , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
                                        , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 110
                                        , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 13)); ?>
```

How do I do it though? As the saved data is a date and not a whole number so my comparison won't work... Looking for simplest solution here without replying on plugins or other external assets and just some simple code if possible.

Thanks.

EDIT: So based on the comments below I have added:

```
public function checkDOB($check) {
        return strtotime($check['dob']) < strtotime();
    }
```

But what do I put in the strtotime to check the age is above or EQUAL to 13?

Comment: Use a beforeSave method in your model, use strToTime of the given DOB and the current date, subtract given from current, get number of years, check if it's greater than 13. If it is, save it.

Comment: Yes, definitely custom validation rule instead of beforeSave. This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209968/cakephp-how-to-validate-my-d-o-b-field-so-that-the-age-will-not-be-greater-than

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep track of the birthdate rather than the age, and then autocalculate the age by finding the time since the birthdate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom validation rule in your model:

```
public function checkOver13($check) {
  $bday = strtotime($check['dob']);
  if (time() < strtotime('+13 years', $bday)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

This uses a neat feature of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) that lets you easily do date calculations on a particular date.

To use the rule:

```
'dob' => array(
  'age' => array(
    'rule' => 'checkOver13',
    'message' => 'You must be over 13 years old'
  )
)
```

Comment: To use the rule I just did: `'age' => array(
          'rule' => 'checkDOB',
             'message' => 'You must be over 13 years old'
         )`