# Age validation to be made for member or non-member using CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-3.0

I am just starting with CakePHP, 
We have a CakePHP 3.x application to manage activities for a Senior Citizen Organization.

We manage members and non members. To be registered to an activity as member, age is mandatory and should be > 49.

To be registered to an activity as a non member, age is not mandatory;
In template (.ctp) we have this code:

```
<?= $this->Form->control('birthdate, ['label' => 'Birth date', 'required' => true, 'monthNames' => $mois, 'minYear' => 1900, 'maxYear' => date('Y')]) ?>
```

So no validation is done for now..

Question:
Where should that validation be made? Template, Model, Controller?
And how should it be coded?

Answer (score 2):

I think You may add validation in Model

For further reference you can use this:[Cakephp How to validate my D.O.B field so that the age will not be greater than the period of residence entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209968/cakephp-how-to-validate-my-d-o-b-field-so-that-the-age-will-not-be-greater-than])

I hope this will help you to solve your issue- thanks!